# Why is the value of `this` in a dom event listener callback not the window?

Tags: javascript, html, object, ecmascript-6

Let's look at the following code:

```js
const div = document.getElementById('foo');
div.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<div id="foo">click me</div>
```

This button will always log the dom element I'm clicking. I've always known this to be true, and I know that I can use an arrow function here to make the value of `this` the `window`. We are assuming non arrow function syntax for this question.

To my knowledge, the value of `this` gets its value based on how the enclosing function is invoked. The callback of this event listener certainly doesn't get called on the dom element.

In my mind, when the `div` gets clicked, it adds the anonymous function to the message queue. When the queue is empty it invokes the anonymous function in a global execution context (perhaps this is where I'm wrong).

If it is in the global execution context where this anonymous function gets invoked, shouldn't the value of `this` be the window?

Which leads back to the title question, why is the value of `this` in a dom event listener callback not the `window`? (Assuming the callback is not an arrow function)

Answer (score 2):

It's because it's a method attached to the `div` object - think of it like this:

```
const div = {
    addEventListener: function(event, callback) {...}
};
```

In this example, `this` would refer to `div` as you would expect.

This is what's actually happening in your code, only it's being defined differently.

Comment: interesting, so the callback gets tacked on as a property of the dom element?

Comment: The callback is the anonymous function, and `this` in a method (unless nested objects/arrow functions) would refer to the parent object, so yes.

Comment: what gets me thinking about this is basically how `setInterval` and `setTimeout` work. Even though these methods are defined on the `window` those callbacks use the `window` as `this` i always thought this was because when the callbacks get on the stack they are invoked at the global level. Similarly, isn't that how event callbacks get executed as well? I thought they were the same execution context

Answer (score 0):

> #### [The value of this within the handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler)
>
> It is often desirable to reference the element on which the event handler was fired, such as when using a generic handler for a set of similar elements.
>
> If attaching a handler function to an element using `addEventListener()`, the value of [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) inside the handler is a reference to the element. It is the same as the value of the `currentTarget` property of the event argument that is passed to the handler.

Comment: can't argue with the docs, seems like the behaviors of an event callback would be similar to that of a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` callback, but i guess it's not